# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have difficulty with the following code. I think it lies in my sql statement.
I get the error :

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

```
    Dim strSql5 As String = "SELECT  * FROM dbo.ontledings where plaasblok = '" & plaasblokparsversoeke & "' and analisedatum  = " & laastedatum.Date
    MsgBox(strSql5)

    Dim dtb5 As New DataTable
    dtb5.Clear()

    Using cnn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=GIDEON-E-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS2014;Initial Catalog=SkeduleringDatabasis;Integrated Security=True")
        cnn.Open()
        Using dad5 As New SqlDataAdapter(strSql5, cnn)
            dad5.Fill(dtb5)
        End Using
        cnn.Close()
    End Using


    Dim laasteontleding As Decimal = dtb5.Rows(0)("suiker")
```

I get the laastedatum from the following code :

```
    Dim laastedatum As Date = dtb4.Rows(0)("last")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: In which line did you get the error?

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to build Sql Queries. That's one of the problems I was talking about in your previous question

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SELECT *, use SELECT field list. Then use Field(Of T) to get the date information strongly typed. Always used Option Strict On.

Example reading order data from Microsoft NorthWind database orders table, note the field retrieval.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim EmployeeId As Integer = 2
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = My.Settings.ConnectionString}
            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                cmd.CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                    SELECT [OrderID]
                          ,[CustomerID]
                          ,[EmployeeID]
                          ,[OrderDate]
                          ,[ShipCountry]
                      FROM [NORTHWND.MDF].[dbo].[Orders]
                      WHERE [EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID
                      ORDER BY CustomerId  
                    </SQL>.Value

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", EmployeeId)

                cn.Open()

                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Console.WriteLine("id: {1} date: {0}",
                                      row.Field(Of Date)("OrderDate").ToShortDateString,
                                      row.Field(Of String)("CustomerId"))
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Get first date

```
Dim rowOneOrderDate As Date = dt.Rows(0).Field(Of Date)("ORderDate")
```